# Capture click event from child frame into parent frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click, jquery-events

Right, this is weird. I have done loads of Googling and found hundreds of articles which seem to point me in the right direction, but none seem to work.

Here's the latest incarnation of what I am trying to do:

Parent Page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $('#mainWindow').ready(function () {
       $('#mainWindow').contents().find('#clickThis').live('click', function () {
           alert('Click detected!');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="mainWindow" name="mainWindow" src="myMainPage.aspx" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
    <iframe src="myOtherPage.aspx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Framed Page (sitting in mainWindow)

```
<html>
    ' LOADS OF STUFF INCLUDING:
    <li id="clickThis">Click This</li>
</html>
```

So obviously what I am trying to do here is to run some code in the Parent Page when a user clicks the button in the child frame.

It needs to work `live` so if the page in the frame changes it is still captured by the parent (this element exists on all pages which will be loaded into the frame)

I have been able to run codes across iFrames, from parent to iFrame and from iFrame to iFrame following various other searches, but running from iFrame to parent is causing issues.

The above code does nothing, and neither do any of the other options I have tried!!

***Edit** should add, all files are on the same server, the cross domain issue is not a problem

Comment: `live` is deprecated. use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @Rune ok, but neither work with the code above!

Answer (score 4):

[This works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/xNGA9/75/):

```
$('#myframe').contents().on('click', function () {
    $('#result').text('clicked');
});​
```

*If you want to capture the events just on a part of the content document, use [`.contents().find(<selector>)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (`<selector>` being e.g. `'body'`) instead of just `.contents()`*

**Something to watch out for**: All of your pages must exist under the same `document.domain` or the JavaScript calls will fail. You will see this surfaced as a security exception in your console. This happens due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: This is driving me insane! Wasting so much time on something so simple!! Your `jsFiddle` works in Chrome, but not FIrefox, but translating the same code to my project doesn't work in either!

Answer (score 2):

Way, way way too late of an answer, but I had the same issue and the code below works in all browsers:

```
$('#myiframe').on('load', function () {
   $(this).contents().on('click', function () {
      alert('Click detected!');
   })
})
```

It attaches `onclick` handler but only after iframe has been loaded. I am leaving this here for posterity and for anybody else looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to capture some data as well inside the iframe, this will work for you:
There is an iframe element with multiple images in it. The iframe is rendered inside of parent page. Whichever image you click inside the iframe, that image's id is sent back to the parent.

Inside iframe:

```
<script>
function vote(e) {
            myMessage = e;
            window.parent.postMessage(myMessage, "*");
            return false;
        }
</script>

        <body><div>
        <img id="Image1" src="file:///Users/abcd/Desktop/1.jpeg" width="200px" onclick="vote(this.id)">
        </div></body>
```

Inside parent page:

```
</script>
function displayMessage (evt) {
        var message = "You voted " + evt.data;
        document.getElementById("received-message").innerHTML = message;
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        // For standards-compliant web browsers
        window.addEventListener("message", displayMessage, false);
    }
    else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", displayMessage);
    }
</script>

 <body><div id="received-message"></div></body>
```

This will not only capture the click but also capture the id of the element being clicked inside the iframe. Also, this does not require JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `find` to bind an event listener to an element that might not be there? Why not just try:

```
$('#mainWindow').ready(function()
{
    $('#clickThis').on('click',function()
    {
        alert($(this).html());//or something
    });
});
```

BTW: since your code is inside the ready callback of `#mainWindow`, there is no need to use `$('#mainWindow')` a second time, as this will scan the DOM tree a second time. Just use `this` or `$(this)`, as it will reference the mainWindow element anyway.

If on doesn't work for you, don't forget to check if you have the latest version of jQuery included, too. That, too can be the reason why on isn't working.

Comment: I don't really know why I was using `find` I'd just been trying loads of different examples I found online. For some reason your example won't work either. Either with `live` or `on` I'm not getting the `alert`

Comment: try `$($('#mainWindow').document).ready`, since iFrames have their own document object